# prevent ESLint from failing the build with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, eslint

How can I prevent ESLint from failing the build but preserve the rule severity.

I have a jenkins job, that should succeed also if there are listing issues. This was possible with gulp but i don't know how to do it with grunt.

Comment: Way back in the day, I created https://github.com/gyandeeps/gruntify-eslint which has a flag to not fail using `silent` flag... just of the usecase u have...

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.